# Active Reports Image split up

Tags: c#, .net, report, activereports

I'm using `ActiveReports` in my application. It a continuous report which contains 100+ pages. The report has `SubReports` too. It contains both text and few images.

Now when the report is generated the image in the main report gets splitup into two and shown. For example, if the page 5 has a image it splits and First half is shown in the 5th page and 2nd half is shown in the 6th page.

After few searches i found inserting `page break` helps. But how do i find the `report` is ending its page and it has `image` and so i should need to insert a `page break`? Or Is there a better solution?

[image: Image Break]

Answer (score 0):

set the section keeptogether property to true and ActiveReports will make sure the section stays together and does not split across pages.   hope this helps.

Comment: The section has many panels, making the property to true skips if the whole section doesn't fit. I just need only the image panel to check if fits.

Comment: Any other way to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

After few searches i found the answer from [here](http://arhelp.grapecity.com/groups/topic/richtextbox-keep-it-together-man/)

Consolidating the Q&A type,

2 ways to achieve this,

There is no `KeepTogether` property for a control. The only way to specify to keep it together is to have the control in a section with the section’s keep together property set to true. In this case, that solution would not work.

**1.** One of the approach would be, to have a `PageBreak` control right above the control and you would have to dynamically calculate where you are on the page. You could then use the `MeasureParagraphHeight` method to see what height the control will need to be to render it’s text, and set the PageBreak’s enable property to true if it is not going to fit on the page. In this approach you would need to also take into account your margin heights.

If there are `SubReports`, Unfortunately `SubReports` don’t always follow the `KeepTogether` rules. Subreports should actually be avoided unless absolutely necessary since you’re running an extra report & that adds overhead.

**2.** In this case I would actually use another groupheader section that’s `datafield` property is set to something that repeats for each row of data. Then move the existing controls in the detail section to that inner `GroupHeader`. The controls will still display one row of data. Then the control can be isolated in it’s own section with the section’s KeepTogether property set.

I have used the Second method to achieve my work.